# Create new class instance from function return value - one-liner

Tags: php, class

Does there exist a one-liner (yes, I love them) to create new instance of a class based on the returned string of a function?

```
$obj = new {functionThatReturnsAStringValue()}();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand what you want, but i think you can do it that way:

```
$obj = ($class = functionThatReturnsAStringValue()) ? new $class() : null;
```

Comment: also, if `functionThatReturnsAStringValue()` return `false` you can change `: null;` to `new OtherClass()`

Answer (score 2):

```
function getObject()
{
  return 'DateTime';
}

$datetime = call_user_func(function ($obj) { return new $obj; }, getObject());
```

Comment: i think, using `call_user_func()` not best practice.

Comment: Depends on your needs. It's also probably not best practice to try to dynamically call a class using a string-returning function on a single line. ;)